# Toolbar wont stay in place when scrolling horizontally

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a toolbar similar to the twitter one. problem is when the browser is not wide enough and i scroll to the side the toolbar follows instead of staying put horizontally so that scrolling left does not show the hidden part of the toolbar.

How do i get the effect i want?

My CSS:

```
.toolbar {
    visibility: visible;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 22px;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 2px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    border-bottom: 3px ridge #dddddd;
}
```

example:
http://t2.technion.ac.il/~snayish/m/toolbar.html

css:
http://t2.technion.ac.il/~snayish/m/style.css

Comment: Can you show us more code? Is the example online?

Comment: How can the browser never be wide enough?... you have the toolbar set to 100% so it should always be 100%.  Can you post a URL to your page or a JSFiddle that demonstrates what you're seeing?

Comment: Also with `position:fixed`, it will always be pinned at the specified position of your **window** no matter how you scroll... this is the expected behavior.

Comment: Looking at your posted example:  I'm in Safari and no matter how narrow/wide I make my window, I do not see any horizontal scrollbars.

Comment: i used chrome and see the problem... @sparky672 maybe try it there...

Comment: @Mike:  Chrome & Safari are both Webkit... if they're showing something different, we have bigger problems.

Comment: @nayish:  You don't think it was important to mention this in your OP?

Comment: @nayish:  As I tried to mention earlier, we have a contradiction.  If the toolbar is 100% wide, how can it exceed the width of the window?  In this regard, I think Safari is being more compliant than Chrome.  The best I can recommend is that you re-program the toolbar's contents so that it never exceeds the 100% width.  Why not post the relevant HTML in the OP too?

Comment: @nayish: The link to your CSS is broken.

Comment: @nayish:  I am asking you how/why you get horizontal scroll-bars when the width of the element is set to 100%.

Comment: @nayish:  I am not posting any more answers for you to down-vote since I don't even know for sure what you want.  However, you have a fixed container set to 100% width.  You have a 900 pixel wide element inside the container and you have an empty element outside the container set to 900 pixels wide.  Of course you're either going to chop it off (Safari) or cause it to scroll (Chrome) when you narrow it down less than 900 pixels.  Why don't you set `.toolbar .inner-toolbar { }` and `.frame { }` to `90%` instead of `900px`?  When you narrow the window, the contents will resize accordingly.

Comment: @nayish:  Exactly!  You'll have to decide if you want it chopped off (fixed width content) or not chopped off (% content that resizes)... I don't see how you're going to have it both ways in pure HTML/CSS.

Comment: @nayish:  Typically the burden is on the OP to clearly specify what they want.  You never mentioned doing this with JavaScript, otherwise, why not just look at Twitter's JavaScript.

Comment: Hi guys. Please don't use the comment section of a post as a chat forum. It's for appropriate feedback to the *post*, not for prolonged discussion about it. If you end up discussing the post, bringing up things for improvement, make sure those bits end up *in the post*, then delete the comments. The questions and answers are the important parts on this site, not the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on twitter its done with JS you cant solve this with pure CSS.

I would solve it like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/Tt3rw/1/

(getting the scrollLeft position and moving the left position of the content part of your banner according to this)

Comment: a css solution would be better, but it can't be done i am afraid. I still wonder why i got 2 down-votes on this one.

Comment: Maybe because your answer was not specific enough in the beginning, +1 for changing that...